# Entity Framework Primary Key Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a very simple C# class, which contains one primary key. I am using EF 6 with code-first and I have two questions:

1. How do I make a primary key as an `Identity` in code-first (and how to not make it an identity)? Some of my classes need the PK to be an identity (auto increment on addition) and some need it to be assigned by code.
2. When I try to save the class to the database using:

   ```
   // This code is actually wrapped by a BusinessContext Class to encapsulate the ORM representation
   context.Costumers.Add(costumer); //exception is here!
   context.SaveChanges();
   ```

   I get the following exception for my class, on the `Add` method:

   > One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
   >
   > M.Costumer: : EntityType 'Costumer' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
   >   Costumers: EntityType: EntitySet 'Costumers' is based on type 'Costumer' that has no keys defined.

and this is the class itself:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class Costumer : BindableBase
    {
        private string name;
        private string city;
        private Estado state;
        private int costumerId;

        [Required]
        [StringLength(500)]        
        public string Name
        {
            get { return this.name; }
            set { SetProperty(ref name, value); }
        }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string City
        {
            get { return this.city; }
            set { SetProperty(ref city, value); }
        }

        [Required]
        public State State
        {
            get { return this.state; }
            set { SetProperty(ref state, value); }
        }

        [Required]
        [Key]
        public int CostumerId
        {
            get { return this.costumerId; }            
        } 
    }
}
```

The class does have a `[Key]`, so how come there is an exception saying there isn't a key?

Comment: a `Key` can't have a private setter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity Framework must have a getter and a setter for any `[Key]` attributes.

If you want to designate to EF that you will be generating the values for this field, you can use `[DatabaseGeneratedOption.None]`.

the [DatabaseGeneratedOption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedoption(v=vs.110).aspx) Enumeration has 3 different values:

- Computed -- The database generates a value when a row is inserted or updated.
- Identity -- The database generates a value when a row is inserted.
- None -- The database does not generate values.

The default for a key value is `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`

Comment: But in this particular class I want the DB to generate the ID automagically using an Identity...so I removed the setter, since it wont make much sense have the hability to set something the DB should be setting.....how do I configure it as an identity?

Comment: So, why Microsoft forces you to have a setter if even them are making Identity as the default? (which means the set will be ignored anyways)

Comment: the setter *isn't* ignored, it is used internally by EF to set the value in the entity from the return on the insert.  It's also used to populate the value when you do a lookup from the database.

Answer (score 0):

use [DatabaseGeneratedOption.None] attribute in your Key.